# Changing hostname causes unity to doesn't startup

Tags: unity, 13.04

I changed my hostname from `jv01-carlos.becker` to `jv01-carlosbecker` in `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/hosts`.

After that, unity just never loads. I could open a browser and everything creating a folder in desktop and opening it, then poiting to `/usr/share/applications`.

How can I fix that? I couldn't find any relevant logs in `/var/log/syslog`.

Thanks in advance

---

BTW: I switched back to my old hostname, and the issue persisted.

---

EDIT: [`~/.xsession-errors`](https://gist.github.com/caarlos0/5698587)

EDIT2: Just remembered that I also upgrade the kernel to `3.8.0-23`

Comment: Is there anything in `~/.xsession-errors`?

Comment: I've updated the question with a gist to the file contents (https://gist.github.com/caarlos0/5698587). Thaks

Answer (score 2):

Fix it with, after a lot of digging and other things that I'm not sure if affected anything:

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity
```

Have no idea about what happened.